# How to rename a function in Django model without causing AttributeError during migration

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django **model.py**

```
def cool_function(value):
    pass

class Method2(models.Model):
    inputfile_param     = models.FileField(validators=[cool_function])
```

What I want to do is to rename `cool_function()` to some name `even_cooler_function()`.

But when I did this

```
python manage.py make migrations
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cool_function'
```

How can I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Open the migration file that has the import to the old function
and adjust the reference.

from `cool_function()` to `even_cooler_function()` in your relevant migration file.